# Construct points $C$ and $D$ such that the distance from $C$ to $D$ is $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> Suppose that we have points $A$ and $B$, and the distance from $A$ to $B$ is $1$.
> Construct points $C$ and $D$ such that the distance from $C$ to $D$ is $\sqrt{2}$

So far I have found how to solve this problem when the line segment has length $2$. But in this case the length is $1$. So this is what I have done

Construct the line through $A$ and $B$. Next, construct a semicircle centred at $B$ with radius $AB$. Sat it meets he line at $A$ and $C$. Now consider the bisector of $A$ and $C$. This line passes through $B$ and intersects the semicircle at a point, $D$. Clearly, the length of the line segment  $BD$ is $1$. Forming a right triangle of legs $BC$ and $BD$ and hypotenuse $CD$, the Pythagorean theorem would complete the construction. Am I right?
[image]

I need to know if there are any steps that are redundant or if any of them can be replaced by something more elemental. I would also like to know if there is another (elementary too) way to do this exercise.

Comment: This is pretty much as simple as it gets with straight-edge compass constructions. If you’ve discussed how to form a square in the past, you could simplify this to “Form a square with side $AB$ as one of the sides, and take the diagonal.” But forming the square will require constructing perpendicular bisectors, so I doubt you get any simplification from doing this.

Comment: @MarkSaving Ok, so what I've done is okay?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was just responding to your question about whether any steps are redundant or whether there’s a simpler path, and I forgot to acknowledge that your solution was in fact correct.